# if data not found in database insert data else update data

Tags: java, mysql

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SLCMQueryConstant.SELECT_ROLE_FOR_MAP);
pstmt.setInt(1, roleid);
pstmt.setInt(2, pageid);

rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    PageDTO PageDTo = new PageDTO();
    PageDTo.setRolePageMapID(rs.getInt("Role_Page_Map_ID"));
    System.out.println(rs.getInt("Role_Page_Map_ID"));
    if (rs.getInt("Role_Page_Map_ID") == 0) {
        String query = SLCMQueryConstant.INSERT_INTO_ROLE_PAGE_MAP;
        int count = 1;
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(count++, pageid);
        pstmt.setInt(count++, roleid);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(conn.getAutoCommit());
        conn.commit();
    } else {
        String query = SLCMQueryConstant.REUPDATE_INTO_ROLE_PAGE_MAP;
        int count = 1;
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(count++, pageid);
        pstmt.setInt(count++, roleid);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(conn.getAutoCommit());
        conn.commit();
    }

}
```

in particular code,if table doesn't found entry corresponds to roleid and pageid
  then while is not executing if an entry found then update is happen.
    How to do insert operation if table doesn't found role_Page_Map_ID?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (rs.next()) {

     //Do something
}
else {
    INSERT
}
```

Comment: I have done. but my reputation is below an average as I am new joiner.